# Why is my array storing multiple copies of the same value

Tags: java

This is what the output looks like:

```
Name: [a, b, c, d]
Years flown: [1, 11, 7, 2]
Bonus amount: [0.0, 2410.0, 0.0, 2410.0, 1206.0, 0.0, 2410.0, 1206.0, 515.0]
Average traveled miles: 666.66
Number earning bonus: 3
Total bonus amounts: $10157.00
Number of miles flown: [222.22, 555.55, 1000.0, 888.88]
Pilot count: 4
```

Can anyone see what's wrong? I'm only supposed to be getting 4 bonus amounts since there are 4 names, but I get all these extra amounts. Also, as for the number earning a bonus, there should only be 2 because you can only earn a bonus is your number of miles flown is greater than the average, but it shows 3 people earning a bonus.

```
public class PilotBonus {
   public static void main(String[] args) {        
      while (question.equalsIgnoreCase("n")) {
         if (pilotCount < MAX_PILOTS) {
            pilotCount++;       
            pilotName = getName(pilotName);
            numYrsFlown = getYrsFlown(numYrsFlown);
            numMilesFlown = getMilesFlown(numMilesFlown);
            avgMilesFlown = getAvg(pilotCount, numMilesFlown);
            bonusEligibility = determine(avgMilesFlown, numMilesFlown);
            bonusAmt = getBonusAmt(bonusEligibility, numYrsFlown, bonusAmt);
            numEarningBonus = getNumEarningBonus(bonusEligibility, numYrsFlown);
            totalBonus = calcTotalBonus(bonusAmt);
         }
         else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Too many pilots");
         }    
      }         
      if (question.equalsIgnoreCase("y")) {
         print(pilotName, numYrsFlown, bonusAmt, avgMilesFlown, numEarningBonus, 
            totalBonus, numMilesFlown, pilotCount); 
      } 
   }

   public static boolean determine(double avgMilesFlown, double[] numMilesFlown) {

      for (double d : numMilesFlown) {
         if (d > avgMilesFlown) {        
            return true;
         }          
      }
      return false;
   }

   public static double[] getBonusAmt(boolean bonusEligibility, int[] numYrsFlown, double[] bonusAmt) {

      double bonus = 0;

      if (bonusEligibility == true) {
         for (int i : numYrsFlown) {       
            if (i >= 9) {
               bonus = 2410.00;
            }
            if (i < 9) {
               bonus = 1206.00;
            }
            if (i < 6) {
               bonus = 515.00;
            }
            if (i < 2) {
               bonus = 0.00;
            }

            bonusAmt = Arrays.copyOf(bonusAmt, bonusAmt.length + 1);
            bonusAmt[bonusAmt.length - 1] = bonus;
         }        
      }

      return bonusAmt; 
   }

   public static int getNumEarningBonus(boolean bonusEligibility, int[] numYrsFlown) {

      int count = 0;

      for (int i : numYrsFlown) {
         if (i >= 2 && bonusEligibility == true) {
            count++;
         }
      }

      return count;
   }
```

Comment: Can you provide a stand alone test which replicates your problem?  Have you tried debugging your code using your debugger?

Comment: I'm not getting a compiler error, if that's what you mean

Comment: No I suggest you write a stand alone test and use your debugger to debug your code. I didn't mention errors, compiler or otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove `double[] bonusAmt` parameter from `getBonusAmt` and add variable with same name to beginning of this method

```
double[] bonusAmt = new double[0];
```